# Continuous surjective function from [0,1] to (0,1)

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a Continuous surjective function from [0,1] to (0,1)?

I think there's none. Since we could take a sequence $f_n$ to approximate $1$ and by continuity and subjectivity then there's corresponding sequence $x_n$ in $[0,1]$ that approximate a certain point $a$ since $[0,1]$ is compact then that point $a$ must be in $[0,1]$.So there's $f(a)=1$ a contradiction.

I am not sure if I am right or wrong....kind of confused by my own argument...

Comment: The continuous image of a compact set is compact. If you have not seen a proof of this statement, try proving that if $f$ is continuous and has domain $[0,1]$, then it attains its maximum (and its minimum).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the image of any compact set under a continuous map is itself compact. Since $[0, 1]$ is compact and $(0, 1)$ is not, there is no such function.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right way. The following fact will be helpful for you

> Let $X$ ba a Huasdorff compact space and $f$ is continuous on $X$, then $f(x)$ is also compact.

---

Your proof is basically right. There is a small mistake. **"You can not say that $x_n$ approximate $a$, however, $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence which converges $a$."**

Comment: Can you comment on my way of "proving" it ?

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. First, you can choose a sequence of points $x_n$ in $[0,1]$ so that the corresponding function values $f(x_n)$ converge to $1$; e.g., choose $x_n$ so that $f(x_n)\gt1-\frac1n$. However, it's not certain that the sequence $x_n$ converges to anything; the chosen points may jump around like crazy. However, there is a basic theorem of analysis (the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem) which says that *any bounded sequence of real numbers has a convergent subsequence*. So you can replace the original sequence $x_n$ with a subsequence converging to a point in $[0,1]$, and the corresponding values $f(x_n)$ still converge to $1$, etc.